# Selected object in list

Tags: python, scripting

I'm trying to make it so that the script stops whenever the object that is selected is not inside of a certain list. From the text below, you can tell that the ['Empty.00'] is both the object that I have selected and the object that is inside of my list.

```
print(bpy.context.selected_objects)

[bpy.data.objects['Empty.001']]

print(bpy.context.scene.extra.Empty_list)

[bpy.data.objects['Empty.001']]
```

For the code I thought that this would work: I had the intention that the code would do `return{'FINISHED'}` for selected objects that are not inside of the "Empty_list".

```
S_object = bpy.context.selected_objects
Empty_list = bpy.context.scene.extra.Empty_list

        if S_object not in Empty_list:
            return{'FINISHED'}
```

But for reason, it does `return{'FINISHED'}` even when I used ['Empty.001'], so the result is that the script stops. And I have no idea why.

Comment: both are lists. you can't check them as you did in the if statement use Sets and if set1.issubset(another set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Empty_list = bpy.context.scene.extra.Empty_list

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    if object not in Empty_list:
        break
```

Comment: Note overriding the builtin type `object` is not recommended (builtin words are displayed in orange in formatted code snippets). Usually `obj` is used. Cheers